# How to create a faster jQuery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have created an autocomplete using jQuery which takes data encoded in json from my mysql database.

It works well but the problem is that it takes 4-5 sec to show the suggestions even though to select all the products from mysql dataabse takes 0.0008 sec. Here is my code:

The input:

```
<form action="product_detail1.php" method="GET">
  <input name="search" style="padding: 3px 0px 3px 30px;" type="text" id="skills" class="search1" placeholder="Cerca per codice">
  <label style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 4px; left: 3px; font-size: 18px;" for="skills" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="search"></label>
</form>
```

The autocomplete:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search1.php'
    });
  });
```

And thye search1.php file which selects the data from dataabse and encodes them:

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName); 
$searchTerm = $_GET['term']; 
$query = $db->query("SELECT codice 
                     FROM articoli 
                     WHERE codice LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' 
                     ORDER BY codice ASC"); 
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $data[] = $row['codice'];
} 
echo json_encode($data);
```

If there is a way to make this faster please can you tell me? I searched in the internet but didn't find a way.Thanks!

Comment: Create index on codice field if you have not already created on it.

Comment: Well if the query runs on 0.0008 secs its unlikley to be the query that is the time consuming part of the process

Comment: Have you looked at the Network tab in your browsers debugger to see what else might be taking all the time?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes that what I'm saying, but I dont know where to find the solution

Comment: It depends how big is the data returned and btw how many time the request made to complete

Comment: _“even though to select all the products from mysql dataabse takes 0.0008 sec”_ – so what, you are _not_ selecting all data here, so this has absolutely no significance here.

Comment: @CBroe I inserted the same query in sql and it took only 0.0008 sec  to execute.

Comment: One thing that can be done is prefetch the data on page load in an array and then use the array as autocomplete source.

Comment: @Akshay How to prefetch the data? And does this really optimises the performance of the autocomplete?

Comment: @Daniel - During page load get the data via `ajax` into an `array` before you call `autocomplete`. So you already have data for autocomplete and you need not to go the server again so the autocomplete response will be faster.

Comment: @Akshay Any answer of how is this done? I will vote up if works out.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a workaround -

```
     var skills = new Array();    
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "search1.php",
         type: "GET",
         contentType: contentType,
         success: function(data, status, xhr){
             skills = data; // ["test", "test2", "test3"]
             $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
                  source: skills
             });
         }, error: function(xhr, status, err) {
             console.error(err);
         }
     });
});
```

Hope this helps !